# Issue with DecimalField, max_digits of django models

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have declared below field in models.py.

```
marks = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, default=3.0)
```

At backend table structure is :

```
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra        |
| marks | float(3,1)    | NO   |     | 1.0     |              |
```

So here default value 3.0 will try to save as 3.00 (decimal places=2) at backend and there will be no space to store left side value 3 right?

For above case,when I give max_digits=3 or decimal_places=1 it is working.

Please help me, whatis exactly happening here from django to mysql db flow?

Comment: did you run makemigrations and then migrate?, check the migration file

Comment: Yes.I did migration too.

Answer (score 25):

`DecimalField` accepts arguments for `max_digits` which is the total number of digits in a decimal number and for `decimal_places` which is the number of decimal places.

If you define `max_digits` to be 3 and `decimal_places` to be 2, the largest number you can save is 9.99. It has 3 digits and 2 decimal places. If `max_digits` is for example 5, and `decimal_places` is 2, the largest number you can save is 999.99.

In your case it doesn't make sense to have maximum 2 digits and to have 2 decimal places, because it can't store 3.00, which has 3 digits. Because 2 digits are already occupied by the decimal places there is no space for digits before the dot. The largest number you can therefore save is 0.99.

Answer (score 4):

these are the definition for max_digits and decimal_places

`max_digits`
The maximum number of digits (those before the decimal point plus those after the decimal point, with leading zeros stripped) permitted in the value.

`decimal_places`
The maximum number of decimal places permitted.